# In a linkedIn article, how can I edit the text in the "Published by" section?

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm writing a linkedIn article and I want to add some text below, in the "Published by" section, explaining what I do and how it relates to the article. I've seen a lot of articles with this feature, but I don't seem to be able to edit it myself.

Example:

[image]

**Does anyone know how to do this?**

Thanks